# 404 is given when trying to access existing controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am working on a fairly new install of CodeIgniter 2.0.

I have a htaccess-file containg this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Going to the URL http://www.estiem.no/ESTIEM/CI/ works, 
but http://www.estiem.no/ESTIEM/CI/site/index does not. It gives a 404. The controller Site exists, and contains the method 'index'

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: is the CI install in the following folder (from root /) `/ESTIEM/CI/` or somewhere else? We are making assumptions here.  Also is your controller called `site`?

Comment: Yes, the CI is installed from root /ESTIEM/CI/

And yes, there is a controller named Site, and is working when the url is http://estiem.no/ESTIEM/CI/

Comment: It would seem there is a lot of people having problems like this. Having it in a subfolder from root seems to generate extra problems...

Comment: No, having CI is subfolder is never a problem. Just do one thing, check if http://www.estiem.no/ESTIEM/CI/index.php/site/index works or not. If it doesn't the problem isn't htaccess.

Comment: Well, the link you suggested does work...

Comment: Also check your request uri configs... I've had a ton of issues with ci2 and routing...

Comment: i checked again, this htaccess works fine for me with CI2.  Hope htaccess is enabled on your system and works - crosscheck this one.

Comment: Peter: If you mean the $config['uri_protocol'], I tried them all.

Shikhar: There was a htaccess-file handling 404s on the system, and was working. I deleted this. Is there a chance the server has restrictions on what I can do in a htaccess-file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove / from index.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that since you have your CI install in a subfolder, you need to account for that in the `.htaccess` rewrite:

> /ESTIEM/CI/

So your `.htaccess` will look like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ESTIEM/CI/index.php/$1 [L]
```

That should fix it (sorry late edit, due to @BrianOrtiz 's comment)

Comment: I don't think its needed, I have been using two apps without this.

Comment: This wouldn't affect routing, just how links are generated.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz, thanks for the kickup to this question, I changed my answer, to something which I think solves the problem, missing subfolder rewrite (as it originally is for `/` root of the site).

Answer (score 0):

It is a htaccess problem, back when everyone passed that code around we found that a lot of hosts didn't like it and you could hack it with a ? or this or that until it ended up looking like a jigsaw puzzle (the condition that is) but using a brilliant htaccess (not sure who the first was but like 500 have taken credit) you will never have to change it again (well not never but it will work 99% of the time un edited):

```
# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Trust me I have had the same issues and spend hours on google when i should have come here or even the CI wiki (since that is the first place I seen it), you would not believe how many issues are solved in CI with just that bit of htaccess. they really should add it to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the controller with: localhost/site/**index.php**/controller

If that does not work maybe because the CI is case sensitive

- localhost/**site**/controller == c:...\site\controller.php
- localhost/**SITE**/controller == c:...\SITE\controller.php

else

```
<?php

controller Mycontroller extends Controller {

}

?>
```

will be named `mycontroller.php` in the controllers folder

---

If all else fails replace your htaccess by this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Put .htaccess file in your site directory